# Python Flask: TypeError: The view function did not return a valid response

Tags: python, angularjs, flask

I have a return statement,however it gives the error `View function did not return a response`. How can I solve this issue?

```
@app.route('/out/', methods=[ 'POST'])
def extract():
        json_request = request.get_json()
        print (json_request)
        data = json.loads(json.dumps(json_request))
        return data

if __name__ == "__main__":
        app.run()
```

My front end is an angular js application which calls the API of Flask in `postman` i am able to get the request but not from the `front end`

front end code

```
  aURL: string = 'http://127.0.0.1:5000/out';
return this.httpClient.post(`${this.aURL}/`,JSON.stringify(request),{headers: headers});
```

Comment: Hi, what is the result of `        print (json_request)`

Comment: its printing `None`

Comment: ok it means your app doesn't receive anything can you print (request.body)

Comment: body >> `{
    "filters": [{
        "id": 1,
        "name": "pool",
        "type": "str",
        "date": ["2019-12-01", "2019-12-03"]
    }]
}`

Comment: Ok the issue seems that the request is not made as json. You need to submit the data as json from the frontend (also with the correct header).
I am very bad at JavaScript but I think you can make it like this: `JSON.stringify(data_dict)`

Comment: welcome :) added my answer to the question, in order to help other users

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to resolve the Question, for the next users. The issue is that Flask did not receive the JSON as JSON.
`print(request.json)` returned a `None` but `print(request.body)` returned the correct body. Which indicates the data was sent not as JSON and/or with a wrong ContentType, fixing the ContentType in the Frontend resolves the issue

Comment: JSON.stringify(request), is not working again showing same error

Comment: can you add to your question the code how you post to the backend

Comment: let me quickly check with a frontend dev, and can you also post the value of `headers`

Comment: accepting everything `const headers = new HttpHeaders({'Access-Control-Allow-Origin':'*'});`

Comment: in the python flask, can you `print(request.headers)`

Comment: and in the headers from the frontend can you try to add "ContentType": "application/json"